# React / javascript addition to array not changing array lenght

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning react native and I'm doing a small app that regists the time of sleep for each day.

I'm using the useEffect() to trigger some modifications of values showed on screen, one of those is the average time `average()` that I update inside that useEffect:

```
const [updateAction, setUpdateAction] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
        console.log("lenght:" + registSleep.length);
        var registed = false;
        if (!isNaN(enteredHours)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < registSleep.length; i++) {
                if (
                    registSleep[i].day === selectedDay &&
                    registSleep[i].month === selectedMonth &&
                    registSleep[i].year === selectedYear
                ) {
                    registed = true;
                    registSleep[i].hours = enteredHours;
                }
            }
            if (!registed) {
                var newReg = {
                    day: selectedDay,
                    month: selectedMonth,
                    year: selectedYear,
                    hours: enteredHours,
                };
                setNewRegist((prevReg) => [
                    ...prevReg,
                    newReg,
                ]); 
            }
            if (registSleep.length != 0) {
                average();
            }       
        }
        console.log("2. lenght:" + registSleep.length);
        setviewInfoAction(!viewInfoAction);
    }, [updateAction]);
```

To debug, as you can see I print to console the lenght before I add a new value to the array of regists `setNewRegist(...)` and as far as I know it should be printing `lenght: 0` and then `2. lenght: 1` but instead it prints `lenght: 0` and then `2. lenght: 0` and on the next trigger `lenght: 1` and then `2. lenght: 1`.

Why the array is not updating on addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//I am considering this
const [ registSleep , setNewRegist ] = useState([])
```

`setNewRegist` is async function, so next statment will execute first in your case `console.log` so it won't have updated `registSleep` .

**So How to check right?**

Tada.... !!! You can check each update of `registSleep` via `useEffect` like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Here you can get updated length
   // as soon as registSleep updates
   console.log(registSleep.length); 
},[registSleep]) // <-- watch for any update on `registSleep`
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `setNewRegist` is useState Hook, where it's value is registSleep

```
const [registSleep, setNewRegist] = useState([ ... ])
```

Two reasons why it's not working. useState Hook is asynchronous, the logic will not stop for the logic inside setState.

```
setNewRegist( ... update registSleep)
console.log(registSleep) // will run before setState finishes
```

However even it did finish in time, registSleep was already set at a fixed value, so it will not change unless the component is rerendered, which is what setState does, to trigger the component to rerender.